# PHP - Regex optimization split string in parts

Tags: php, regex, string

In PHP I try to make a regex to split a string in different parts as array elements.

For example this are my strings :

```
$string1 = "For a serving of 100 g Sugars: 2.3 g (Approximately)";
$string2 = "For a serving of 100 g Saturated Fat: 5.8 g (Approximately)";
$string3 = "For a portion of 100 g Energy Value: 290 kcal (Approximately)";
```

And I want to extract specific informations from these strings :

```
$arrayString1 = array('100 g','Sugars', '2.3 g');
$arrayString2 = array('100 g','Saturated Fat', '5.8 g');
$arrayString3 = array('100 g','Energy Value', '290 kcal');
```

I made this regex :

```
(^For a serving of )([\d g]*)([^:]*)(: )([\d.\d]*)( )([a-z]*)
```

Do you have any idea how to optimize this regex?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it a bit more specific matching the g or kcal and the digits.

To match all examples, you can use an alternation to match either of the alternatives `(?:serving|portion)`

Instead of using 7 capturing groups, you can use 3 capturing groups.

You can omit the first capturing group `(^For a serving of )`and combine the values of the digits and the unit.

```
^For\h+a\h+(?:serving|portion)\h+of\h+(\d+\h+g)\h+([^:\r\n]+):\h+(\d+(?:\.\d+)? (?:g|kcal))\b
```

- `^` Start of string
- `For\h+a\h+(?:serving|portion)\h+of\h+` Match the beginning of the string with either `serving` or `portion`
- `(\d+\h+g)\h+` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits and `g`
- `([^:\r\n]+):\h+` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times any char except `:`, followed by matching `:` and 1+ horizontal whitspace chars
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
  - `\h+(?:g|kcal)` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and either `g` or `kcal`
- `)\b` Close group 3 and a word boundary to prevent the word being part of a longer word

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wDs23f/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/sJruB)

For example

```
$pattern = "~^For\h+a\h+(?:serving|portion)\h+of\h+(\d+\h+g)\h+([^:\r\n]+):\h+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\h+(?:g|kcal))\b~";
$strings = [
    "For a serving of 100 g Sugars: 2.3 g (Approximately)",
    "For a serving of 100 g Saturated Fat: 5.8 g (Approximately)",
    "For a portion of 100 g Energy Value: 290 kcal (Approximately)"
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    array_shift($matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100 g
    [1] => Sugars
    [2] => 2.3 g
)
Array
(
    [0] => 100 g
    [1] => Saturated Fat
    [2] => 5.8 g
)
Array
(
    [0] => 100 g
    [1] => Energy Value
    [2] => 290 kcal
)
```